# How do I count the ocurrence of a data point in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have this table and I want to retain and count only the id in which the strings A and D are most represented. For example, A and D are most represented in the id "abc" than in the "hil" Id.

| string | id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | abc | 0 | 1 |
| A | abc | 2 | 3 |
| B | efg | 1 | 3 |
| A | hil | 5 | 6 |
| A | abc | 6 | 7 |
| D | abc | 7 | 8 |
| D | abc | 1 | 2 |
| D | hil | 3 | 4 |

How can I obtain the id in which those strings are most represented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you can get the most common `id` for each `string` like this:

```r
apply(table(df$id, df$string), 2, function(x) {
   rownames(table(df$id, df$string))[which.max(x)] })
#>     A     B     D 
#>  "abc" "efg" "abc"
```

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I expressed myself badly. I would like to get a single id where both A and D are represented the most times. I don't want the separate id for A and D but the id where both A and D occur the most times.
In any case, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
df %>% 
  filter(string == "A" | string == "D") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  count(id) %>%
  arrange() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice(1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  id        n
  <chr> <int>
1 abc       5
```

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I expressed myself badly. I would like to get a single id where both A and D are represented the most times. I don't want the separate id for A and D but the id where both A and D occur the most times.
In any case, thanks for the reply

Comment: @LucaCorda I edit the code. The code above gives you the highest count of id for A and B. I hope I understood you right.

Comment: thank you again but i don't know why it doesn't work in my dataframe which is larger than this. It gives me an incorrect result. I think there is a problem in slice(1) because it shows me the id of the first line of the tibble which, however, is not the one in which A and D are there more times. How can I change to get the id where A and D are most represented?